# Opt-out of a Documentation Proposal

Tags: support, status-completed, documentation, documentation-proposals

I've opted-in for a Documentation proposal a while back that I believe should *never* be made, which has gained more support since. (I must also add, the sidebar did advertise a tag for it! I blame big suggestive buttons and coffee).

[CodeIgniter **3** Documentation Proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter-3/commit)

The reason I think it should never be made, as it's very version specific. All documentation for CodeIgniter should canonically sit within:

[**CodeIgniter Documentation**](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/codeigniter/topics)

However I don't see a button anywhere, please correct me if I'm mistaken but I don't want to be responsible for bloating the new Docs with dead tags! :)

Unless of course, later down the line - certain topics will be closed for reasons such as duplication etc.

Comment: This seems to be missing the root problem. Allowing user-moderation based tag merges seems to be the better solution over opting out of a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating an alias from [codeigniter-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter-3) (and [codeigniter-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter-2)) to [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter) in Documentation. We'll need to look into putting this in the hands of the community if these cases proliferate. But for now, a meta question should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for that :) I understand it's all very early days!