# What does it mean to commit to a documentation proposal?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-proposals

What exactly does it mean to commit to a documentation proposal?

The only information given is:

*"Once there are 5 committers, the community will be able to document all (some_language_name) topics"*.

Does it also mean that if you commit to a documentation proposal, it is also your responsibility to add and address relevant topics? How important is it to do or not to do that?

 What does SO recommend on who and why a person should  commit to a documentation proposal?

Comment: It is like the old joke about the pig and the chicken and their commitment to a breakfast with ham and eggs.  The pig needs to be a *lot* more committed.  This is the chicken's commitment.  Nothing is going to happen when you are no longer interested in the project.

Comment: It is a very minor bar, but it is a bar nevertheless. You have to find 4 other people who agree that Documentation needs to be created for that tag.

Comment: Honestly, the commitment is less binding than Documentation is functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, among many reasons is why we updated our Tag Proposal page in a recent redesign.

Here's a screenshot of what the page now looks like, for one of the proposed [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/abstract-syntax-tree) on Docs -

> [image]

Among other design and copy updates, we ***changed 'committing' to 'backing'*** thus better implying our original intent.

Given we enforce backers to only be those that have -

- a minimum of 150 rep points AND
- atleast 1 positively scored answer in the said tag

... we believe we will have an invested group backing the creation of the Doc tag. While we encourage these backers to then subsequently create and/or propose topics and engage in the tag, that's not a requirement.

Also as a backer, you will be automatically signed up to receive notifications on updates to the tag - IRs, Proposed Changes, Discussion threads, Topic Requests. 
You can however easily adjust your preferences for these notifications - more info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-notifications).

Answer (score 3):

I have committed to a lot of documentation proposals, and my Stack Exchange inbox (stackexchange.com/users/[myuserid]?tab=inbox) now receives all:

- Improvement requests
- Proposed changes
- Topic requests

for anything I've committed to document. [Opting out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332691/opt-out-of-a-documentation-proposal?rq=1) of notifications is now available for the following:

- Improvement requests
- Proposed changes
- Topic requests